# Project Euler #4 in Haskell

Tags: haskell, programming-challenge, palindrome

[Project Euler #4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) asks:

> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

The code is as follows:

```
module Main where

import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

palindromes :: [Integer]
palindromes = [calcPalindrome a b c | a <- [1..9], b <- [0..9], c <- [0..9]]
    where
        calcPalindrome a b c = 100001 * a + 10010 * b + 1100 * c

is3Digit :: Integer -> Bool
is3Digit n = n >= 100 && n <= 999

isDiv :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
isDiv n d = n `mod` d == 0

-- returns all multiples of 2 3-digit numbers
-- for palindromes
isMultiple :: Integer -> Bool
isMultiple n = not $ null threeMultiples
    where
        multiples :: [(Integer, Integer)]
        multiples = do
            d <- [10..99]
            if n `isDiv` (d * 11)
            then return (d * 11, n `div` (d * 11))
            else []
        threeMultiples :: [(Integer, Integer)]
        threeMultiples = filter (\ (m, n) -> is3Digit m && is3Digit n) multiples

problem4 :: Integer -> Integer
problem4 n =
    head $ filter isMultiple $ sortBy (flip compare) $ filter (< n) palindromes

main :: IO ()
main = do
    _ <- getLine
    contents <- getContents
    let cases = map read $ lines contents
    let results = map problem4 cases
    mapM_ print results
```

I'd appreciate comments on `isMultiple` and `problem4` as they seem rather messy. Any other general comments are welcome too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Proof technique

I was pleasantly surprised at the speed of this algorithm (generating all 6-digit palindromes, then taking the largest one with two 3-digit factors), as compared to the alternative approach (multiplying all 3-digit pairs, then finding the largest product that is a palindrome).  I would have expected the latter to be faster, as factoring is normally a more expensive operation — but you take advantage of a clever [shortcut](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/697096/77144).  That, I suppose, is part of the point of Project Euler questions.

On the other hand, I would consider the program to be slightly incomplete.  The property that the palindrome is divisible by 11 only holds if it contains an even number of digits.  As a counterexample, 101 ∙ 101 = 10201 is a number within the parameters of the question (a palindrome that is the product of two 3-digit numbers) that is *not* divisible by 11.  Your `palindromes` function only generates 6-digit candidates for consideration.  While there is no need for your program to produce a result that requires no human interpretation, it would be desirable to note the assumption (or proof) of the existence of a 6-digit result, at least as a comment.

### Implementation

I am puzzled by your boilerplate `main` function.  Reading an input number as an upper bound on the palindrome candidates seems superfluous.  An excessively large input won't scale the problem to cover 4-digit × 4-digit products, either, as your `palindromes` function is hard-coded to produce 6-digit candidates only.  So, this would have sufficed:

```
problem4 :: Int 
problem4 = head $ filter isMultiple $ sortBy (flip compare) $ palindromes

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print problem4
```

`Integer` is overkill.  The numbers involved fit very comfortably under `maxBound::Int`.

`sortBy (flip compare)` is just the same as `reverse`.  But why reverse anything at all, when you could just generate the palindrome candidates in descending order in the first place?

```
palindromes :: [Int]
palindromes = [calcPalindrome a b c | a <- [9,8..1], b <- [9,8..0], c <- [9,8..0]]
    where
        calcPalindrome a b c = 100001 * a + 10010 * b + 1100 * c
```

`is3Digit` is fine, though I would find `is3Digit n = 100 <= n && n < 1000` more aesthetically pleasing.

`isMultiple` could be better named, and the `do … return` would be better written as a list comprehension.  (See [*Do notation considered harmful*](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Do_notation_considered_harmful).)

```
isProductOfThreeDigitNumbers :: Int -> Bool
isProductOfThreeDigitNumbers n = not $ null threeDigitFactors
    where
        -- All palindromes with an even number of digits are divisible by 11
        factors = [(d, n `div` d) | d <- [11, 22 .. 99 * 11], n `isDiv` d]
        threeDigitFactors = filter (\ (m, n) -> is3Digit m && is3Digit n) factors
```

Then, `problem4` would just be

```
problem4 :: Int
problem4 =
    head $ filter isProductOfThreeDigitNumbers $ palindromes
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'll follow the changes you recommended.

Comment: Nice. I went for the other approach. I'm wondering how much faster this is. Maybe I'm wrong but I would have thought the less efficient approach reflects the level of difficulty of Euler # 4....

Answer (score 1):

I went for simplicity. Here's my attempt

```
import Data.List

isPalindromic::Int -> Bool
isPalindromic n = (==) n' (reverse n')
                where n' = show n
euler4::Int
euler4 = maximum [p | x <- [999,998..100], y <- [999,998..100], let p = x * y, isPalindromic p]
```

As stated by the previous reviewer not as efficient as yours but in my opinion clearer and the right level of complexity :-)

Comment: There is no 'right' level of complexity for Euler, IMO. All questions can be as over-engineered as you want. One prefers, scalability, others prefer speed while a third group would want to keep the complexity down. All are fine. It's Euler after all: practice what YOU want to practice.

Comment: Usually, I'd write a working program with as little complexity as possible, then try to optimize for time, since writing simple programs gets boring (and unsustainable in later Euler problems). :)