# Euler #4: Refined Palindrome in Haskell

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell, functional-programming

This is my attempt at the Problem Euler #4 in Haskell ("Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.")

```
import Data.List

isPalindrome :: Show a => a -> Bool
isPalindrome n = l == reverse l
  where l = show n

maxPalindrome :: (Integral a, Show a) => a
maxPalindrome = maximum $ head . transpose $ allPalindrome <$> [999, 998 .. 1]
  where allPalindrome x = filter (isPalindrome) $ (x *) <$> [999, 998 .. x]
```

To my surprise I didn't see any such optimisation in the snippets I found (the head . transpose is there to only consider the highest of each pairs), which surprised me. However this is still running about 0.5 seconds which I find still slow?

Is there a way to make it run faster? I am aware of [Project Euler #4 in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74665/project-euler-4-in-haskell) however, my question is not about the algorithm I use but about its implementation.

Do you have any other recommendation about my code?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: *"However this is still running about 0.5 seconds which I find still slow?"*

How did you test that? After all, the execution time differs between interpreted and compiled. For example, in GHCi I get 0.27 seconds (consistently), whereas in a compiled variant (`-O2`) I end up with 0.03s (`main = print maxPalindrome`).

Comment: Oh sorry I imported it in ghci and used `:set +s`. Time was 0.8 on the first try, and 0.5 on other tries, even if I closed ghci and opened it back. I did not notice compilation could have such an important speed factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but I would suggest some small changes. Instead of `head . transpose`, I would use `concatMap (take 1)`. This captures your intend to take the first (and therefore largest) number from each `allPalindrome`.

Next, I would use `Int` instead of `(Integral a, Show a)`, since `999 * 999` is smaller than `maxBound :: Int`. Why? Because by [default](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4), `Integer` will be used for `Integral` types, if they were note specified. Therefore, you end up with `maxPalindrome` handled as a `Integer`, which is slower than `Int`.

And last, but not least, I would stop at `111`, since `111 * 111` is a palindrome.

We end up with:

```
isPalindrome :: Show a => a -> Bool
isPalindrome n = l == reverse l
  where l = show n

maxPalindrome :: Int
maxPalindrome = maximum $ concatMap (take 1) $ allPalindrome <$> [999, 998 .. 111]
  where allPalindrome x = filter isPalindrome $ (x *) <$> [999, 998 .. x]

main :: IO ()
main = print maxPalindrome
```

Note that you should compile your code if you want to check its performance.

Alternatively, if you want to keep `maxPalindrome`'s type, use `:: Int`:

```
maxPalindrome :: (Integral n, Show n) => n
maxPalindrome = maximum $ concatMap (take 1) $ allPalindrome <$> [999, 998 .. 111]
  where allPalindrome x = filter isPalindrome $ (x *) <$> [999, 998 .. x]

main :: IO ()
main = print (maxPalindrome :: Int)
```

Comment: I am confused about your comment on using Int rather than `(Integral a, Show a)`. I thought it was a good practice to use `Num a` or equivalent in general, because that was more modular and could be used in any given situation ( granted it doesn't apply here, but I was curious as to wether this good practice was actually a good one at all).
Thanks for `concatMap (take 1)`, by the way, I was so focused on using `head` on partial values I did not realize `take 1` worked too.

Comment: @snow_lemurian_snow in general, that's correct. You want your functions to be general. But in this case, there's no input for your `maxPalindrome` taht determines the resulting type, which makes it already a little bit of a hassle, since functions that have a polymorphic can mess up optimization. For example `genericLength` returns a `Num a => a`, but if you use it like `let l = genericLength xs in fromIntegral l / l`, you'll end up taking the length twice. Since you were interested in performance, I changed it to `Int`.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much, it was very clear. I will look into `Integer` to see how slow it is, and use `Int` when appropriate if I want to speed things up